# How do I copy the list of all file names in my github repo ending with `.cs` to a list/text file or clipboard?

Tags: windows, git, command-prompt

In the git command line in windows, how do I copy the list of all file names in my GitHub repo ending with `.cs` to a list/text file or clipboard?

I am looking for something similar to `git log | clip` which copies the git commit log to clipboard but instead only for files in the git repo folder with the specific file ending of `.cs` for C# files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git ls-files -- '*.cs'
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files for the doc. Redirect the output to a file:

```
git ls-files -- '*.cs' >cs-files.list
```

Comment: How can I get it to copy the file names to the clipboard please? I tried | clip like before, but it did not do anything.

Comment: The same way with `| clip`.

Comment: When I am doing this it is pasting nothing to my clipboard, when I check windows key + v in windows 10, it is literally just nothing not even a blank space. It only works if I use the terminal emulator, I want to do it in windows 10 command prompt.

Comment: Every [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+copy+clipboard+cmd) suggests it must be `clip` or `clip.exe`.

Comment: Yes, but even when I try this in windows command prompt, it does not work.

Comment: If anyone could offer further help to getting this further clarified in how to do same thing in windows command prompt would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `clip.exe` work for you with any other input? Like `echo Test |
clip.exe`

Comment: Yeah, `echo Test | clip.exe ` works but not `git ls-files -- '*.cs' | clip.exe` or clip works for some reason. Additionally `git log | clip` always works fine in command prompt in windows 10.

Comment: Any further clarification and answer on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if `git ls-files -- '*.cs' >cs-files.list` and `cat cs-files.list | clip.exe` work?

Comment: `git ls-files -- '*.cs' >cs-files.list` works and creats a blank .list file `cat cs-files.list | clip.exe` does not work at all.